# Visual Studio 2010 : Can't change target. Gives TargetFrameworkMoniker Error

Tags: visual-studio-2010

I have a console application which has target .NET 2.0

It is very short but full of unsafe code.

I converted it to VS 2010. I run it OK.

When I try to change "target framework" in properties to 3.5 or 4.0 it shows message box:

> TargetFrameworkMoniker: Error parsing application configuration file at line 0. XML document must have a top level element.

the target then stays 2.0 anyway.

Comment: For me it was this same issue when going from .NET to NET 4.5. The solution was part of TFS and turns out I was in offline mode. When I connected back online to my TFS server it all worked fine.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Found the solution. Simply opened app.config in text pad (it was empty for some reason) and pasted:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<configuration>
<startup><supportedRuntime version="v4.0" sku=".NETFramework,Version=v4.0"/></startup></configuration>
```

Answer (score 30):

This happened to me because my project file was marked as "Read Only" in its properties. Changed it, and it was fine.

It also could be caused by read-only app.config/web.config

Answer (score 1):

For me the problem was the web.config file located outside of the project directory.
I moved it back in, and was able to change the target framework.

Answer (score 1):

I have same issue. I solved it by removing write protected attribute of web.config file. It was read only earlier.

Answer (score 1):

For me, my project was using a web.config file that was a linked file back to a web.config in another project. I removed the link, changed the target, then added the link back.

Answer (score 1):

I faced this problem , i solved it by click app.config to open it and  leave it ,then go to properties and upgrade .NET version

Answer (score 0):

I was trying to retarget from .NET 4.5.2 to .NET 4.5 In my app.config, I had to change

```
<supportedRuntime version="v4.0" sku=".NETFramework,Version=v4.5.2" />
```

to

```
<supportedRuntime version="v4.0" sku=".NETFramework,Version=v4.5" />
```

before the project properties page would let me retarget.