# Visual Studio suddenly bombing with errors

Tags: c#, entity-framework, asp.net-core, visual-studio-2019

I am creating a website using ASP.Net Core 5 and EF Core 5.

After I deleted all my migrations in migration folder suddenly Visual Studio starts bombing me with errors as it shown below:

On the top I get this message:
[image]

In the Error List I get:

[image]

And somehow I can not choose a Target Framework any more:
[image]

UPDATE:

Here is the content of the .targets file:

```xml
<!--
***********************************************************************************************
Microsoft.Common.targets

WARNING:  DO NOT MODIFY this file unless you are knowledgeable about MSBuild and have
          created a backup copy.  Incorrect changes to this file will make it
          impossible to load or build your projects from the command-line or the IDE.

This file defines the steps in the standard build process for .NET projects.  It
contains all the steps that are common among the different .NET languages, such as
Visual Basic, and Visual C#.

Copyright (C) Microsoft Corporation. All rights reserved.
***********************************************************************************************
-->

<Project DefaultTargets="Build" xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/developer/msbuild/2003">
  <!-- 
       In VS 2010 SP1 and VS 2012, both supported for asset compatibility, the MSBuild installed 
       as part of them did not enforce using the local ToolsVersion (4.0) in all cases, but instead 
       just used whatever ToolsVersion was in the project file if it existed on the machine, and 
       only forced 4.0 if that ToolsVersion did not exist.  

       Moving forward, we do want to enforce a single acting ToolsVersion per version of Visual Studio, 
       but in order to approximate this behavior on VS 2010 SP1 and VS 2012 as well, we've redirected 
       the targets:  If we're building using 4.X MSBuild (which doesn't define the new reserved 
       property, MSBuildAssemblyVersion), we'll point right back at the 4.0 targets, which still exist 
       as part of the .NET Framework.  Only if we're using the new MSBuild will we point to the current
       targets. 
   -->

  <Choose>
    <When Condition="'$(MSBuildAssemblyVersion)' == ''">
      <PropertyGroup>
        <CommonTargetsPath>$(MSBuildFrameworkToolsPath)\Microsoft.Common.targets</CommonTargetsPath>
      </PropertyGroup>
    </When>
    <Otherwise>
      <PropertyGroup>
        <CommonTargetsPath>$(MSBuildToolsPath)\Microsoft.Common.CurrentVersion.targets</CommonTargetsPath>
      </PropertyGroup>
    </Otherwise>
  </Choose>

  <PropertyGroup Condition="'$(MSBuildAssemblyVersion)' == ''">
     <!-- 
          Overrides for the Microsoft.Common.targets extension targets. Used to make sure that only the imports we specify 
          (hard-coded to 4.0 locations) are used, not the 12.0 locations that would be used by default. 

          NOTE: This logic is duplicated in Microsoft.VisualBasic.targets and in Microsoft.CSharp.targets because those two files 
          import Microsoft.Common.targets from the current directory and thus don't get the benefit of the redirections, so for 
          any changes to this logic in this file, please also edit the other two. 
      -->
    <ImportByWildcardBefore40MicrosoftCommonTargets Condition="'$(ImportByWildcardBefore40MicrosoftCommonTargets)' == ''">$(ImportByWildcardBeforeMicrosoftCommonTargets)</ImportByWildcardBefore40MicrosoftCommonTargets>
    <ImportByWildcardBefore40MicrosoftCommonTargets Condition="'$(ImportByWildcardBefore40MicrosoftCommonTargets)' == ''">true</ImportByWildcardBefore40MicrosoftCommonTargets>

    <ImportByWildcardAfter40MicrosoftCommonTargets Condition="'$(ImportByWildcardAfter40MicrosoftCommonTargets)' == ''">$(ImportByWildcardAfterMicrosoftCommonTargets)</ImportByWildcardAfter40MicrosoftCommonTargets>
    <ImportByWildcardAfter40MicrosoftCommonTargets Condition="'$(ImportByWildcardAfter40MicrosoftCommonTargets)' == ''">true</ImportByWildcardAfter40MicrosoftCommonTargets>

    <ImportUserLocationsByWildcardBefore40MicrosoftCommonTargets Condition="'$(ImportUserLocationsByWildcardBefore40MicrosoftCommonTargets)' == ''">$(ImportUserLocationsByWildcardBeforeMicrosoftCommonTargets)</ImportUserLocationsByWildcardBefore40MicrosoftCommonTargets>
    <ImportUserLocationsByWildcardBefore40MicrosoftCommonTargets Condition="'$(ImportUserLocationsByWildcardBefore40MicrosoftCommonTargets)' == ''">true</ImportUserLocationsByWildcardBefore40MicrosoftCommonTargets>

    <ImportUserLocationsByWildcardAfter40MicrosoftCommonTargets Condition="'$(ImportUserLocationsByWildcardAfter40MicrosoftCommonTargets)' == ''">$(ImportUserLocationsByWildcardAfterMicrosoftCommonTargets)</ImportUserLocationsByWildcardAfter40MicrosoftCommonTargets>
    <ImportUserLocationsByWildcardAfter40MicrosoftCommonTargets Condition="'$(ImportUserLocationsByWildcardAfter40MicrosoftCommonTargets)' == ''">true</ImportUserLocationsByWildcardAfter40MicrosoftCommonTargets>

    <ImportByWildcardBeforeMicrosoftCommonTargets>false</ImportByWildcardBeforeMicrosoftCommonTargets>
    <ImportByWildcardAfterMicrosoftCommonTargets>false</ImportByWildcardAfterMicrosoftCommonTargets>
    <ImportUserLocationsByWildcardBeforeMicrosoftCommonTargets>false</ImportUserLocationsByWildcardBeforeMicrosoftCommonTargets>
    <ImportUserLocationsByWildcardAfterMicrosoftCommonTargets>false</ImportUserLocationsByWildcardAfterMicrosoftCommonTargets>

    <CustomBeforeMicrosoftCommonTargets Condition="'$(CustomBeforeMicrosoftCommonTargets)' == ''">$(MSBuildExtensionsPath)\v4.0\Custom.Before.Microsoft.Common.targets</CustomBeforeMicrosoftCommonTargets>
    <CustomAfterMicrosoftCommonTargets Condition="'$(CustomAfterMicrosoftCommonTargets)' == ''">$(MSBuildExtensionsPath)\v4.0\Custom.After.Microsoft.Common.targets</CustomAfterMicrosoftCommonTargets>
  </PropertyGroup>

  <PropertyGroup Condition="'$(MSBuildAssemblyVersion)' == '' and ('$(TargetFrameworkIdentifier)' == '.NETFramework' or '$(TargetFrameworkIdentifier)' == 'Silverlight' or ('$(TargetFrameworkIdentifier)' == '' and ('$(TargetRuntime)' == 'Managed' or '$(TargetRuntime)' == '')))">
     <!-- 
          Overrides for the Microsoft.NETFramework.props extension targets. Used to make sure that only the imports we specify 
          (hard-coded to 4.0 locations) are used, not the 12.0 locations that would be used by default. Required because 
          Microsoft.Common.targets imports it from the current directory, so we don't get a chance to redirect these in its 
          own redirection targets. 

          NOTE: This logic is duplicated in Microsoft.VisualBasic.targets and in Microsoft.CSharp.targets because those two files 
          import Microsoft.Common.targets from the current directory and thus don't get the benefit of these redirections either, 
          so for any changes to this logic in this file, please also edit the other two. 
      -->
    <ImportByWildcardBefore40MicrosoftNetFrameworkProps Condition="'$(ImportByWildcardBefore40MicrosoftNetFrameworkProps)' == ''">$(ImportByWildcardBeforeMicrosoftNetFrameworkProps)</ImportByWildcardBefore40MicrosoftNetFrameworkProps>
    <ImportByWildcardBefore40MicrosoftNetFrameworkProps Condition="'$(ImportByWildcardBefore40MicrosoftNetFrameworkProps)' == ''">true</ImportByWildcardBefore40MicrosoftNetFrameworkProps>

    <ImportByWildcardAfter40MicrosoftNetFrameworkProps Condition="'$(ImportByWildcardAfter40MicrosoftNetFrameworkProps)' == ''">$(ImportByWildcardAfterMicrosoftNetFrameworkProps)</ImportByWildcardAfter40MicrosoftNetFrameworkProps>
    <ImportByWildcardAfter40MicrosoftNetFrameworkProps Condition="'$(ImportByWildcardAfter40MicrosoftNetFrameworkProps)' == ''">true</ImportByWildcardAfter40MicrosoftNetFrameworkProps>

    <ImportUserLocationsByWildcardBefore40MicrosoftNetFrameworkProps Condition="'$(ImportUserLocationsByWildcardBefore40MicrosoftNetFrameworkProps)' == ''">$(ImportUserLocationsByWildcardBeforeMicrosoftNetFrameworkProps)</ImportUserLocationsByWildcardBefore40MicrosoftNetFrameworkProps>
    <ImportUserLocationsByWildcardBefore40MicrosoftNetFrameworkProps Condition="'$(ImportUserLocationsByWildcardBefore40MicrosoftNetFrameworkProps)' == ''">true</ImportUserLocationsByWildcardBefore40MicrosoftNetFrameworkProps>

    <ImportUserLocationsByWildcardAfter40MicrosoftNetFrameworkProps Condition="'$(ImportUserLocationsByWildcardAfter40MicrosoftNetFrameworkProps)' == ''">$(ImportUserLocationsByWildcardAfterMicrosoftNetFrameworkProps)</ImportUserLocationsByWildcardAfter40MicrosoftNetFrameworkProps>
    <ImportUserLocationsByWildcardAfter40MicrosoftNetFrameworkProps Condition="'$(ImportUserLocationsByWildcardAfter40MicrosoftNetFrameworkProps)' == ''">true</ImportUserLocationsByWildcardAfter40MicrosoftNetFrameworkProps>

    <ImportByWildcardBeforeMicrosoftNetFrameworkProps>false</ImportByWildcardBeforeMicrosoftNetFrameworkProps>
    <ImportByWildcardAfterMicrosoftNetFrameworkProps>false</ImportByWildcardAfterMicrosoftNetFrameworkProps>
    <ImportUserLocationsByWildcardBeforeMicrosoftNetFrameworkProps>false</ImportUserLocationsByWildcardBeforeMicrosoftNetFrameworkProps>
    <ImportUserLocationsByWildcardAfterMicrosoftNetFrameworkProps>false</ImportUserLocationsByWildcardAfterMicrosoftNetFrameworkProps>
  </PropertyGroup>

  <ImportGroup Condition="'$(MSBuildAssemblyVersion)' == ''">
    <Import Project="$(MSBuildUserExtensionsPath)\4.0\Microsoft.Common.targets\ImportBefore\*" Condition="'$(ImportUserLocationsByWildcardBefore40MicrosoftCommonTargets)' == 'true' and exists('$(MSBuildUserExtensionsPath)\4.0\Microsoft.Common.targets\ImportBefore')"/>
    <Import Project="$(MSBuildExtensionsPath)\4.0\Microsoft.Common.targets\ImportBefore\*" Condition="'$(ImportByWildcardBefore40MicrosoftCommonTargets)' == 'true' and exists('$(MSBuildExtensionsPath)\4.0\Microsoft.Common.targets\ImportBefore')"/>
  </ImportGroup> 

  <ImportGroup Condition="'$(MSBuildAssemblyVersion)' == ''">
    <Import Project="$(MSBuildUserExtensionsPath)\4.0\Microsoft.NETFramework.props\ImportBefore\*" Condition="'$(ImportUserLocationsByWildcardBefore40MicrosoftNetFrameworkProps)' == 'true' and exists('$(MSBuildUserExtensionsPath)\4.0\Microsoft.NETFramework.props\ImportBefore')"/>
    <Import Project="$(MSBuildExtensionsPath)\4.0\Microsoft.NETFramework.props\ImportBefore\*" Condition="'$(ImportByWildcardBefore40MicrosoftNetFrameworkProps)' == 'true' and exists('$(MSBuildExtensionsPath)\4.0\Microsoft.NETFramework.props\ImportBefore')"/>
  </ImportGroup>

  <Import Project="$(CommonTargetsPath)" />

  <!--
      Prepare to import project extensions which usually come from packages.  Package management systems will create a file at:
          $(MSBuildProjectExtensionsPath)\$(MSBuildProjectFile).<SomethingUnique>.targets
          
        Each package management system should use a unique moniker to avoid collisions.  It is a wild-card import so the package
        management system can write out multiple files but the order of the import is alphabetic because MSBuild sorts the list.
    -->
  <PropertyGroup>
    <ImportProjectExtensionTargets Condition="'$(ImportProjectExtensionTargets)' == ''">true</ImportProjectExtensionTargets>
  </PropertyGroup>

  <Import Project="$(MSBuildProjectExtensionsPath)$(MSBuildProjectFile).*.targets" Condition="'$(ImportProjectExtensionTargets)' == 'true' and exists('$(MSBuildProjectExtensionsPath)')" />

  <PropertyGroup>
    <ImportDirectoryBuildTargets Condition="'$(ImportDirectoryBuildTargets)' == ''">true</ImportDirectoryBuildTargets>
  </PropertyGroup>

  <!-- 
        Determine the path to the directory build targets file if the user did not disable $(ImportDirectoryBuildTargets) and
        they did not already specify an absolute path to use via $(DirectoryBuildTargetsPath)
    -->
  <PropertyGroup Condition="'$(ImportDirectoryBuildTargets)' == 'true' and '$(DirectoryBuildTargetsPath)' == ''">
    <_DirectoryBuildTargetsFile Condition="'$(_DirectoryBuildTargetsFile)' == ''">Directory.Build.targets</_DirectoryBuildTargetsFile>
    <_DirectoryBuildTargetsBasePath Condition="'$(_DirectoryBuildTargetsBasePath)' == ''">$([MSBuild]::GetDirectoryNameOfFileAbove($(MSBuildProjectDirectory), '$(_DirectoryBuildTargetsFile)'))</_DirectoryBuildTargetsBasePath>
    <DirectoryBuildTargetsPath Condition="'$(_DirectoryBuildTargetsBasePath)' != '' and '$(_DirectoryBuildTargetsFile)' != ''">$([MSBuild]::NormalizePath('$(_DirectoryBuildTargetsBasePath)', '$(_DirectoryBuildTargetsFile)'))</DirectoryBuildTargetsPath>
  </PropertyGroup>

  <Import Project="$(DirectoryBuildTargetsPath)" Condition="'$(ImportDirectoryBuildTargets)' == 'true' and exists('$(DirectoryBuildTargetsPath)')"/>

  <ImportGroup Condition="'$(MSBuildAssemblyVersion)' == ''">
    <Import Project="$(MSBuildExtensionsPath)\4.0\Microsoft.NETFramework.props\ImportAfter\*" Condition="'$(ImportByWildcardAfter40MicrosoftNetFrameworkProps)' == 'true' and exists('$(MSBuildExtensionsPath)\4.0\Microsoft.NETFramework.props\ImportAfter')"/>
    <Import Project="$(MSBuildUserExtensionsPath)\4.0\Microsoft.NETFramework.props\ImportAfter\*" Condition="'$(ImportUserLocationsByWildcardAfter40MicrosoftNetFrameworkProps)' == 'true' and exists('$(MSBuildUserExtensionsPath)\4.0\Microsoft.NETFramework.props\ImportAfter')"/>
  </ImportGroup> 

  <ImportGroup Condition="'$(MSBuildAssemblyVersion)' == ''">
    <Import Project="$(MSBuildExtensionsPath)\4.0\Microsoft.Common.targets\ImportAfter\*" Condition="'$(ImportByWildcardAfter40MicrosoftCommonTargets)' == 'true' and exists('$(MSBuildExtensionsPath)\4.0\Microsoft.Common.targets\ImportAfter')"/>
    <Import Project="$(MSBuildUserExtensionsPath)\4.0\Microsoft.Common.targets\ImportAfter\*" Condition="'$(ImportUserLocationsByWildcardAfter40MicrosoftCommonTargets)' == 'true' and exists('$(MSBuildUserExtensionsPath)\4.0\Microsoft.Common.targets\ImportAfter')"/>
  </ImportGroup>

   <!-- Fix up FrameworkPathOverride, which is primarily used to determine the location of mscorlib.dll in the 
        (relatively uncommon) situation where the reference assemblies, in which it's usually found, are not 
        installed.  -->
   <PropertyGroup Condition="'$(MSBuildAssemblyVersion)' == ''">
      <FrameworkPathOverride Condition="!Exists('$(FrameworkPathOverride)\mscorlib.dll')">$(MSBuildFrameworkToolsPath)</FrameworkPathOverride>
   </PropertyGroup>
</Project>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

References are crash because of not belong this framework. There is solved subject about that.
[Visual Studio 2010 : Can't change target. Gives TargetFrameworkMoniker Error](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2485281/12278235)